# Can not access files and folders in var/www

Tags: apache2.4

I installed apache2 server and i cant only access files in www not subfolders and other files.

Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /xx/yy.php on this server.
Apache/2.4.6 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

Answer (score -2):

You may check the permissions on the `o` type. Sounds like root may be the only person with write privileges to the subfolders in the `www` directory.